# What is the probability of strictly increasing digits in a randomly generated 4 figure number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I make a $4$ digit number with each digit chosen at random from $\{0,1,...,9\}$, with repetition allowed. How do I find the probability that the digits in the number are in strictly increasing order?

I don't quite see how to proceed (unless naively writing out all possible combinations)?

Comment: Do you mean four-digit numbers or four-digit strings, meaning that $0$ can appear in the first position?

Comment: After resolving the question/comment of @N.F.Taussig in order to have a satisfactory *event* two things must happen: [1] The 4 digit number (or 4 digit string) must be composed of 4 distinct digits [2] These 4 distinct digits must be in strictly increasing order.  Suppose (for example) that the numbers involved are the distinct elements in set $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$.  How many 4-digit numbers can be formed using each element in set $S$ exactly once, and how many of these 4-digit numbers will be in the proper order?

Comment: For simplicity, assume that zero filled 4 digit numbers are allowed.  How many 4 digit numbers can be formed where there are $10$ separate choices for each digit?  Further, how many ways are there to choose $4$ distinct elements from a set of $10$ distinct elements?  Related : see [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Answer (score 0):

The first digit cannot be greater than 6, because with 7, 8, or 9 as the first digit it is not possible to create a 4 digit number with strictly increasing digits.

Let's denote the possibility of the first digit as A, then as the first digit is restricted with the set {0, 1, ..., 6} we have $$P(A)=\frac{7}{10}$$

The second digit is restricted with the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} by the same requirement of strictly increasing digits. Furthermore, the probability of the second digit is conditioned by the first digit. Denoting the probability of the second digit as B and the value of the first digit as x we have this

| 1st digit | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P(B|x) | $\frac{7}{10}$ | $\frac{6}{10}$ | $\frac{5}{10}$ | $\frac{4}{10}$ | $\frac{3}{10}$ | $\frac{2}{10}$ | $\frac{1}{10}$ |

Further, the third digit is also restricted with the relative set {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} and its probability is conditioned by the second digit. Let's denote the probability of the third digit as C and the value of the second digit as y.

| 2nd digit | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P(C|y) | $\frac{7}{10}$ | $\frac{6}{10}$ | $\frac{5}{10}$ | $\frac{4}{10}$ | $\frac{3}{10}$ | $\frac{2}{10}$ | $\frac{1}{10}$ |

The fourth digit is restricted with the set {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} and its probability is conditioned by the third digit. Let's denote the probability of the fourth digit as D and the value of the third digit as z.

| 3d digit | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P(D|z) | $\frac{7}{10}$ | $\frac{6}{10}$ | $\frac{5}{10}$ | $\frac{4}{10}$ | $\frac{3}{10}$ | $\frac{2}{10}$ | $\frac{1}{10}$ |

So actually the probability of the number with strictly increasing order is the sum of all the possible products of the 4 digits probabilities like $\frac{7}{10}*\frac{7}{10}*\frac{7}{10}*\frac{7}{10}$.

Eventually we can define the final formula as $$\sum\frac{7*a*b*c}{10^4}$$ for each a, b, and c $\in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ where $a\geq b \geq c$